# VSTO Custom XML ribbon tab contains a group not specified in the XML

Tags: vsto

I have a custom XML ribbon tab in a VSTO Excel Add-in. The XML for the custom ribbon tab is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="EMP">
        <group id="EMPForms" label="Measurement Study">
          <button id="EMPStudy"
                  label="EMP Study"
                  screentip="EMP Data"
                  supertip="Measurement Study Data"
                  onAction="OnEMPData"/>
          <button id="StudySetup"
                  label="Study Setup"
                  screentip="Setup"
                  supertip="Measurement Study Setup"
                  onAction="OnStudySetup"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

There is only one group specified in the XML.

When I run the Add-in, I get two groups. The first is "Custom Toolbars".  The second is "Measurement Study".  The "Custom Toolbars" is not specified in the XML below.

[image: Ribbon tab with two groups.]

Is there a way to prevent groups or controls from other ribbon tabs from appearing on a custom ribbon tab?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check out other add-ins and Excel documents (they may contain a custom ribbon UI).

There is no way to hide controls or groups on a custom ribbon tab if you don't know their IDs. The best what you can do is to use the `startFromScratch` attribute which allows hiding the built-in ribbon controls. Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thanks for the references.  The "startfromscratch" is not a solution for my add-in.  It removes all of the standard Excel ribbon tabs.  I still want to be able to use the functionality of Excel.  Would you know of any up-to-date books on VSTO?  Most of the books are at least ten years old.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the "Custom Toolbar" group on my custom ribbon is the "Team Foundations Add-in".

Below are the steps that resolved this issue.

1. Start Excel.
2. Go to File | Options.
3. Click the "Add-ins" item in the list box on the left-hand side of the Excel Options dialog.
4. Select the "COM Add-ins" item of the Manage combo box.
5. Click the "Go..." button.
6. Clear the check box for the "Team Foundation Add-in" entry and click the "OK" button.

The "Custom Toolbars" group is no longer in the custom ribbon tab.

[image: Custom ribbon after the removal of Team Foundations]

Comment: In this case, we are no longer using Team Foundations, so this works.  I think that a better solution might be to programmatically remove any items from the custom tab that do not exist in the XML.  Ideally this would remove items from the my custom tab while allowing us to keep the Team Foundations custom tab.